# how to program the apple menu bar in WxPerl?

Tags: perl, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I am just starting out with WxPerl. I generated a simple frame with a button in wxformbuilder, generated the XRC, and successfully used the XRC in my Perl code. So far so good.

Right now I am developing on OS X and I notice that the Apple menu becomes unresponsive when my Wx application runs. Also the menu next to the Apple menu is just "perl", it seems to default to whatever the application name is. If I just run a perl script it uses the name of the perl interpreter. Ok, fine. But how do I custumize the Apple menu bar items in WxPerl. My Google searches are totally useless on this one so far. Any pointers to further documentation or advice?

Comment: This may be a more generic question of how to integrate your GUI with the OS? I suspect you'd have the same thing to resolve with Gtk+, say? So maybe search for that first, how to integrate your application, regardless of the toolkit.